# Is there a name for the grand Greyhawk campaign?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, greyhawk

The Village of Hommlet module, T1 was originally released as a stand alone adventure. A planned sequel got put on ice but the material was eventually recompiled and expanded into a super-module, T1-4, The Temple of Elemental Evil.

A year later this was revised and republished alongside A1-4. At this point these unrelated modules were made to join in to one another to form a campaign. To cap this off, the amalgamated GDQ series, Queen of the Spiders became the finale.

Does this overarching grand campaign - T1-4, followed by A1-4, followed by GDQ1-7, have an official or commonly used name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**

While it was certainly possible to run the three supermodules T1-4 Temple of Elemental Evil (L1-8), S1-4 Scourge of the Slavelords (L7-11), and GDQ1-7 Queen of the Spiders (L8-14) in sequence, it wasn't necessary - and, while when they published the combined SotS they mentioned using it to continue ToEE, ToEE doesn't mention it and most folks ran them separately or interspersed with the many, many other modules available.  It was a little more common to combine A1-4 and GDQ1-7, and GDQ has a "Revenge of the Slavelords" section in it, but not super common, for time reasons if nothing else.

There were many "series" of modules back in the day, and all three of these were published separately first and then republished as mega-modules - there was no original connective tissue between the three module storylines, and only very cursory bolting together was done when they were repackaged as supermodules; considering them one campaign is more marketing than reality. The most significant addition, The Revenge of the Slavelords section in GDQ1-7, basically says "what if a slavelord got away and came seeking revenge and dumped the GDQ adventure lead in their lap when they died". In addition, the Slavelords adventures are fairly fatal, being originally tournament modules.

As a result, running all three together was mainly aspirational, and rare enough there was never a name for it. It's hard to prove a negative, but I've been a diligent Greyhawk player and GM since AD&D 1e, own the originals of all these adventures and pretty much every Greyhawk product ever, subscribed to Dragon Magazine since about issue 96, was a Triad (regional coordinator) for the Living Greyhawk campaign, and participated in online RPG discussions since rec.games.frp.dnd, and have the Greytalk  mailing list archived since Feb 1997.

Comment: Tournament modules? As in, to be run at a con? How could anyone finish ToEE in one session (or even a few)?

Comment: @Adeptus Not exactly; way back when, D&D at conventions was often run as a tournament, with competitive aspects. Those aspects largely fell by the wayside over the years.

Comment: Only the A's were tourney modules, but the answer is "in chunks".  And you didn't have to finish, you had to score better than the other teams.  T1-4 was actually just T1 originally and then got expanded into "T1-4", the others were actually combined.